# Preprocessing of dynamically added series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello I would like to ask how to properly instantiate and process a dynamically added series in Highcharts.

I am bringing about an instance of series like this:

```
var newSeries = new Highcharts.Series();
var newData = [];
date = Date.parse(newDate() +' UTC');
name = 'datapoint name';

newData.push([date, name]);

newSeries.name = 'Somename';

//newData variable processing
newSeries.data = newData;
newSeries.color = "#EEEEEE";
newSeries.showInLegend = false;
newSeries.index = -1;

chart.addSeries(newSeries);
```

With this code, I was able to add a new series in a Highchart object runtime. however, I would like to do some additional processing with my series object before adding it up to the actual chart.

I've tried:

`newSeries.marker.enabled = "false";`

`newSeries.marker.states.hover = "false";`

`newSeries.index = -1; //to be able to send the series at the backmost part of the chart`

but failed to achieve desired results.

If possible, can someone point me to the right direction on how to properly instantiate a `series` object with a `marker` object inside it?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT: THE RIGHT ANSWER CARE OF GREG**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add each point as an object then you have control over the markers as follows:

```
function addSeries(chart) {

        var newSeries = new Highcharts.Series();
        newSeries.name = 'Tokyo';
        newSeries.data = [{y: 1}, {y:20}, {y:23}, {y:11}];
        newSeries.zIndex = -1;

         for (var i = 0; i < newSeries.data.length; i++) {
             var datum = newSeries.data[i];
             datum.marker = {
                 enabled: false,
                 states: {
                     hover: {
                         enabled: false,
                         lineColor: '#ff0000'
                     }
                 }
            };
         }

        chart.addSeries(newSeries);     

    }
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LrvB9/

Comment: Thanks Greg for providing me this insight. It never occured to me to approach it via data points. I'm marking this as the right answer as well as editing the question.